# Data Binding Exercise Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

So, I'm trying to get some practice implementing some data binding in an app, but I keep getting a reference error, saying that the

"name SubtopicButton does not exist in the namespace 'using:TestApp.Models'"

Maybe somebody else can point to what I'm missing, but here are the relevant pieces of code, so maybe I just overlooked something.

Update: here's the full XAML instead if that sheds some more light on it

```
<Page
x:Class="TestApp.SubtopicPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TestApp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:data="using:TestApp.Models"
mc:Ignorable="d">


<Grid Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="125"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Back" Height="100" Width="100" Tapped="{x:Bind backButtonTapped}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="40">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/backButton.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
     </Button>

    <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind SubtopicButtons}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:TestApp.Models.SubtopicButton">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Width="300"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="16"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>

</Grid>
</Page>
```

then here is the Explorer view

[image]

then here is the file SubtopicButton.cs

```
namespace TestApp.Models
{
public class SubtopicButton
{
    public string SubtopicName { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}

public class SubtopicButtonManager
{
    public static List<SubtopicButton> GetSubtopicButtons()
    {
        var subtopicButtons = new List<SubtopicButton>();

        subtopicButtons.Add(new SubtopicButton { SubtopicName = "Gender Roles", Image = "Assets/femaleMaleSymbol.jpg" });
        subtopicButtons.Add(new SubtopicButton { SubtopicName = "Meeting Proceedings", Image = "Assets/femaleMaleSymbol.jpg" });
        subtopicButtons.Add(new SubtopicButton { SubtopicName = "Concept of Time", Image = "Assets/femaleMaleSymbol.jpg" });
        subtopicButtons.Add(new SubtopicButton { SubtopicName = "Business Ethics", Image = "Assets/femaleMaleSymbol.jpg" });
        subtopicButtons.Add(new SubtopicButton { SubtopicName = "Greetings & Personal Reference", Image = "Assets/femaleMaleSymbol.jpg" });
        subtopicButtons.Add(new SubtopicButton { SubtopicName = "Cultural Pitfalls", Image = "Assets/femaleMaleSymbol.jpg" });
        subtopicButtons.Add(new SubtopicButton { SubtopicName = "Personal Space", Image = "Assets/femaleMaleSymbol.jpg" });
        subtopicButtons.Add(new SubtopicButton { SubtopicName = "Negotiation and Ideas of Public Image", Image = "Assets/femaleMaleSymbol.jpg" });

        return subtopicButtons;
    }
}
```

}

and finally here is the code behind the XAML page that includes the property SubtopicButtons (of type list) that I referenced as the Item Source.

```
    public sealed partial class SubtopicPage : Page
    {

         private List<SubtopicButton> SubtopicButtons;



         public SubtopicPage()
         {
             this.InitializeComponent();
             SubtopicButtons = SubtopicButtonManager.GetSubtopicButtons();
         }
```

All of this being said, the only part that throws an error is that part I included in the XAML at the top, but I included all of it because I'm kinda at a loss. what am i not getting? thanks in advance for any help you guys can give

Comment: In my case, i don't use `x:Bind SubtopicButtons` as bind, i just put {Binding} - ItemsSource="{Binding}" and inside of `<DataTemplate>` i leave without nothing, just refer the GridView to your List inside of SubtopicPage() `GridView.ItemSource = yourlist`

Comment: try adding the full path for your `SubtopicButton` in your xaml. `<DataTemplate x:DataType="data:TestApp.Models.SubtopicButton">` Can you include the entire XAML content?

Comment: Ok, seems like there's some sort of computer magic going on here. I tried to clean rebuild and nothing changed, so I went about tinkering away at it, couldn't figure it out, exited, and came back in through this save file. Then, it decided that it was going to start working again, and accepted it, and it seems to run and compile now just fine. Not sure what happened, but thanks everybody for the help